# Update React Child Animated Component

Tags: reactjs, animation

i want to update my child component with new props from Parent.

My Parent Component :

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
        logo:{opacity:1,top:0}
    }
}

componentWillMount(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        this.setState({logo:{
            top:100,
        }});
    }.bind(this),5000);
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <AnimView  opacity={this.state.logo.opacity} top={this.state.logo.top}>
            <LocalImage
                source={require('./assets/img/logo.png')}
                originalWidth={701}
                originalHeight={330}
                Percentage={1.6}
            />
          </AnimView>
        </View>
    );
}
```

my child component:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
        duration: 1000,
        opacity: new Animated.Value(0),
        top: new Animated.Value(0),
        left: new Animated.Value(0),
        right: new Animated.Value(0),
        bottom: new Animated.Value(0),
    }
}
componentDidMount() {
    let duration = this.props.duration ? this.props.duration : this.state.duration;
    Animated.parallel([
        Animated.timing(this.state.opacity,{toValue: this.props.opacity,duration : duration}),
        Animated.timing(this.state.top,{toValue: this.props.top,duration : duration}),
        Animated.timing(this.state.left,{toValue: this.props.left,duration : duration}),
        Animated.timing(this.state.right,{toValue: this.props.right,duration : duration}),
        Animated.timing(this.state.bottom,{toValue: this.props.bottom,duration : duration})
    ]).start();
};

render() {
    return (
        <Animated.View style={{...this.props.style,opacity: this.state.opacity,top:this.state.top,left: this.state.left,right: this.state.right,bottom: this.state.bottom}}>
            {this.props.children}
        </Animated.View>
    );
}
```

at first child fade in with the opacity in parent given.
but i want it to move top or .... after a mean while.
but the new props that i give in parent with componentWillMount is not changing the state of the child..?

Comment: Look at componentWillReceiveProps(props). This function gets the latest props sent from Parent to child, and you can update your state then https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops

Comment: thanks,but can u tell me how to use it?

Comment: Sure. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you need to understand is that when classes are instantiated, the constructor is called only the first time. Which is why in cases where say the Child state depends on Parent, and if Parent state changes, the state changes are reflected back to the Child via a callback called componentWillReceiveProps(props).

Your child component will look like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
        duration: 1000,
        opacity: new Animated.Value(0),
        top: new Animated.Value(0),
        left: new Animated.Value(0),
        right: new Animated.Value(0),
        bottom: new Animated.Value(0),
    }
}

componentWillReceiveProps(props){
    if(props){
        this.setState({
            duration: 1000,
            opacity: new Animated.Value(0),
            top: new Animated.Value(0),
            left: new Animated.Value(0),
            right: new Animated.Value(0),
            bottom: new Animated.Value(0),
        });
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    let duration = this.props.duration ? this.props.duration : this.state.duration;
    Animated.parallel([
        Animated.timing(this.state.opacity,{toValue: this.props.opacity,duration : duration}),
        Animated.timing(this.state.top,{toValue: this.props.top,duration : duration}),
        Animated.timing(this.state.left,{toValue: this.props.left,duration : duration}),
        Animated.timing(this.state.right,{toValue: this.props.right,duration : duration}),
        Animated.timing(this.state.bottom,{toValue: this.props.bottom,duration : duration})
    ]).start();
};

render() {
    return (
        <Animated.View style={{...this.props.style,opacity: this.state.opacity,top:this.state.top,left: this.state.left,right: this.state.right,bottom: this.state.bottom}}>
            {this.props.children}
        </Animated.View>
    );
}
```

So every time changes in the Parent are reflected in the Child, componentWillReceiveProps will be called, and you can update the Child state with the latest props.